# How to use libsvm to obtain support vectors (SVs) in python

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

In matlab, the libsvm has a variable called SVs, we can use it to easily get SVs, but in Python, when I use this variable, it's not what I want. So, I'd like to ask how libsvm gets support vectors in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
support_vector_coefficients = model.get_sv_coef()
support_vectors = model.get_SV()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried and found that it can be realized.But there's another problem, when I output support vectors in the console, each support vector is one more dimension than the original data. It goes like this:
original data: 1:0.027027, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1
output data: 1: 0.027027, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, -1: 0.0
There was a -1:0.0 at the end